# Am I calculating percentages wrong?

Tags: probability, percentages

Let's say someone enters a competition where the winner is select randomly. To enter you just post a comment. Now there are 1,300 entries and 17 prizes, so the chance to win a prize is `1/1,300*17*100 = 1.3%`.

But if someone decides to cheat and posts 100 comments, hell have a 130% chance to win `(100/1,300*17*100)`. How is that possible? If `TotalComments - YourComments = >=17` then you have less than a 100% chance to win, because there is still the chance for any other 17 comments other than your 100 to be selected.

Can someone tell me where my calculation formula is wrong? If you didnt get the formula it's

```
nOfYourComments/nOfTotalComments * nOfPrizes * 100
```

Comment: You need to consider each comment independently. Hint: it is easier to calculate the chance of **not winning anything**, despite having cheated thus.

Comment: What do you mean each comment independently? I assume nOfTotalComments is what you're talking about, but how would i consider them independently?

Comment: You can only add probabilities when they are for independent events. You arrived at a probability of $130\%$ by adding the probability of winning of each of his $100$ comments. But the events of each winning are not independent. If they were independent, then there would be a probability of $0.013^{100}$ of all the comments winning, which is ridiculous, since only $17$ can win.

Comment: @PaulSinclair - Do you mean "you can only add probabilities when they are for _mutually exclusive_ events"?

Comment: @antkam - No, I meant independent. If knowing the outcome of one event influences the probability of another event, then you cannot add the bald probabilities (probability without the additional information).

Comment: @PaulSinclair - but $P(A) + P(B) = P(A \cup B)$ iff $A, B$ are mutually exclusive...  and the OP seems to want to calculate $P(\text{win some prize})$

Answer (score 1):

If the cheater puts in $100$ tickets, then there is some chance he will win more than $1$ prize.  That's where the math needs to change.

- Your calculation ${100 \times 17 \over 1300} \approx 1.3$ actually shows the expected (a.k.a. average) number of prizes he would win. That's why it can be $> 1$.  However, the fact that it is $> 1$ does not mean he will win something for sure.  It's still possible the number of prizes he wins $= 0, 1, 2, 3, 4,\dots$
- To calculate the probability he will win *something*, i.e. at least $1$ prize, you need a different method.

  - Any specific ticket will lose with probability $ = a = 1 - \frac{17}{1300} \approx 0.987$.
  - So probability that all of them lose $= b = a^{100} \approx 0.268$.
  - So probability that he will win something = $1 - b \approx 0.732 = 73.2\%$.